# Are Nested/Child JPA Entities required to have a value when performing UPDATE operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a `Section` entity. `Section` entity has a nested `GradeLevel` entity annotated with `@OneToOne`

**Section**

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Section{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private GradeLevel gradeLevel;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private Boolean isActive = true;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated = LocalDateTime.now();

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "date_last_updated")
    private LocalDateTime dateLastUpdated = LocalDateTime.now();

}
```

**GradeLevel**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class GradeLevel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code; //GL-01, GL-02...

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String description; //Kinder 1, Kinder 2, Grade 1....
    private String category; //Elementary School, Junior Highschool, Senior Highschool

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private Boolean isActive = true;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated = LocalDateTime.now();

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "date_last_updated")
    private LocalDateTime dateLastUpdated = LocalDateTime.now();

}
```

The `@OneToOne GradeLevel gradeLevel;` creates a foreign key in the `Section` table that references to `GradeLevel`'s `ID` column.

The table looks like this:

[image]

Now if I want to update just the `name` of the `Section` and pass just the Section **ID** and new Section **Name** *without the **GradeLevel ID*** request sample below,

> {
> "id" : 1,
> "name" : "Venus" }

The compiler complains about a `null` `GradeLevel` `ID`

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.jordan.cdoautoformsettingsservice.entities.GradeLevel was altered from 1 to null...
```

This gives me the impression that when we have nested JPA entities with `@OneToOne` (or `@OneToMany`...), we are required to provide the ID of the nested Entity. In this case, it wants the `ID` of the `GradeLevel`

I fails to complete the **UPDATE** operation.

**ServiceImpl.java** (UPDATE method) below

```
@Override
    public Section updateSection(Section request) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("request : "+request);
        Long sectionId = request.getId();
        Optional<Section> optionalSection = sectionRepo.findById(sectionId); //retrieve the section we want to update
        if(!optionalSection.isPresent()){
            throw new Exception("Section with ID: "+request.getId()+ "is NOT FOUND");
        }
        GradeLevel gradeLevel = optionalSection.get().getGradeLevel();
        gradeLevel.setId(request.getGradeLevel().getId());
        logger.debug("GradeLevel Properties: ");
        logger.debug("GradeLevel ID: "+gradeLevel.getId());
        logger.debug("GradeLevel CODE: "+gradeLevel.getCode());
        logger.debug("GradeLevel DESCRIPTION: "+gradeLevel.getDescription());
        logger.debug("GradeLevel CATEGORY: "+gradeLevel.getCategory());

        Section section = optionalSection.get();
        section.setName(request.getName()); //replace current section name with section name FROM REQUEST
        section.setDateLastUpdated(request.getDateLastUpdated());
        section.setIsActive(request.getIsActive());
        section.setGradeLevel(gradeLevel);

        return sectionRepo.save(section);
    }
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion or thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check if the retrieved (Section.Grade.id) has a value first? before you attempt to UPDATE?  I mean in theory when you did findBy it should have retrieved all the information of Grade, (Which means No Null Data)?

Comment: @SMA Oh, my bad. The line `gradeLevel.setId(request.getGradeLevel().getId());` in the ServiceImpl.java is what's causing the `null`. The request doesn't have a gradelevel id and I was setting it to the gradelevel.

Removing that line fixed the problem.

Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

this is error due to auto generated entity will generate new section id at every time if you add a constructor in Section.java that has argument id value. then save function work fine

Section.java

```
package com.example.updatehibernate.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@Entity


public class Section{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @OneToOne
   private GradeLevel gradeLevel;

   @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
   private Boolean isActive = true;

   @CreationTimestamp
   @Column(name = "date_created")
   private LocalDateTime dateCreated = LocalDateTime.now();

   @UpdateTimestamp
   @Column(name = "date_last_updated")
   private LocalDateTime dateLastUpdated = LocalDateTime.now();


   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public GradeLevel getGradeLevel() {
       return gradeLevel;
   }

   public void setGradeLevel(GradeLevel gradeLevel) {
       this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
   }

   public Boolean getActive() {
       return isActive;
   }

   public void setActive(Boolean active) {
       isActive = active;
   }

   public LocalDateTime getDateCreated() {
       return dateCreated;
   }

   public void setDateCreated(LocalDateTime dateCreated) {
       this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
   }

   public LocalDateTime getDateLastUpdated() {
       return dateLastUpdated;
   }

   public void setDateLastUpdated(LocalDateTime dateLastUpdated) {
       this.dateLastUpdated = dateLastUpdated;
   }

   public Section(Long id, String name, GradeLevel gradeLevel, Boolean isActive, LocalDateTime dateCreated, LocalDateTime dateLastUpdated) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
       this.isActive = isActive;
       this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
       this.dateLastUpdated = dateLastUpdated;
   }

   public Section(Long id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;

   }

   public Section() {
   }
}
```